# How do I connect mysql in the first time?

Tags: c#, mysql

An error occurred When i use C# to connect mysql in first time.

the error message is:

> Connection open error . Authentication to host 'localhost' faied.

...but in the second time,it become normal.

this is my connect string

```
DefaultConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Database=DatabaseName;Uid=root;Pwd=123456;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add:

```
ConnectionReset=True;
```

.this command is supposed to make one more trip and reset the connection.

Comment: my connectstring wasn`t contain this property.when i restart myservice,this error will occurr in the first time.  but in the another time it will not happend. /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: Got timeout reading communication packets. this is my mysql err log